# Yum install a package with all required dependent packages

Tags: linux

I am trying to install imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64.rpm on CentOS7.
after downloading it, I typed as follows "yum install imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64.rpm".
However, it requires a lot of extra packages as below.

```
[root@ww-convert2 tmp]# yum install imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Examining imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64.rpm: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
Marking imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package imagemagick.x86_64 0:6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: lib64magick-6Q16_2 = 6.8.9.9 for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: fedora.cs.nctu.edu.tw
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.8(LIBJPEG_8.0)(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libIlmImf-2_2.so.22()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcgraph.so.6()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgvc.so.6()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjbig.so.1()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.8()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libopenjp2.so.7()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng16.so.16()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.5()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package graphviz.x86_64 0:2.30.1-21.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: graphviz-2.30.1-21.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4()(64bit) for package: graphviz-2.30.1-21.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXmu.so.6()(64bit) for package: graphviz-2.30.1-21.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXaw.so.7()(64bit) for package: graphviz-2.30.1-21.el7.x86_64
---> Package imagemagick.x86_64 0:6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: lib64magick-6Q16_2 = 6.8.9.9 for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.8(LIBJPEG_8.0)(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libIlmImf-2_2.so.22()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjbig.so.1()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.8()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng16.so.16()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.5()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
---> Package openjpeg2.x86_64 0:2.3.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gd.x86_64 0:2.0.35-26.el7 will be installed
---> Package imagemagick.x86_64 0:6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: lib64magick-6Q16_2 = 6.8.9.9 for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.8(LIBJPEG_8.0)(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libIlmImf-2_2.so.22()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjbig.so.1()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.8()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng16.so.16()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.5()(64bit) for package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64
---> Package libXaw.x86_64 0:1.0.13-4.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXmu.x86_64 0:1.1.2-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXpm.x86_64 0:3.5.12-1.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64 (/imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64)
           Requires: libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64 (/imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64)
           Requires: libjbig.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64 (/imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64)
           Requires: libjpeg.so.8(LIBJPEG_8.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64 (/imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64)
           Requires: libIlmImf-2_2.so.22()(64bit)
Error: Package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64 (/imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64)
           Requires: lib64magick-6Q16_2 = 6.8.9.9
Error: Package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64 (/imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64)
           Requires: libwebp.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64 (/imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64)
           Requires: libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64 (/imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64)
           Requires: libjpeg.so.8()(64bit)
Error: Package: imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64 (/imagemagick-6.8.9.9-4.2.mga5.x86_64)
           Requires: libpng16.so.16()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I googled every single required package to install one by one but every package has other dependency...
Is there something simple that I can install all the required packages at once during the installation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yum fetches packages from registered repositories in your system, some packages might require that you manually add the corresponding respository (or repositories).

In your case, I see that you are trying to manually download the package then install it with yum. In this case, you **must** also download (manually if yum doesn't find them in registered repositories) dependencies and install them before you install the desired package.

A good website to download a package with its dependencies is: https://pkgs.org/

However, as far as I know this website, you should download every dependency one by one separately.

Tell me you if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am just wondering if it is better to dowload *.tar.gz and compile? because of all the complicated dependencies.

Comment: I have another question for you. I checked out the website pkgs.org and would like to donwload java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64.rpm. Is there a way that I can download this package with required packages on the website or Can I add the website to my repo list? if so, could you explain it a bit? thanks,